# XCODE WKWebView execaute javascript within the document

Tags: swift, xcode, wkwebview

I have managed to run a webview app with Xcode. My next task is to click on a button to run a javascript method build within the webpage.

The scenario is on my tabview item i have a link to domainname/menu.php and once this is load i would need xcode to call a javascript method named "openMenu()".

Is this possible?

Thank you in advance

I have tried webView.evaluateJavaScript but did not get it to work.